# FatalErrorException in RedirectionListener.php line 46: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm having a problem with FOSUserBundle.

I have a redirection listener to prevent users from using the app without being logged in, here's the code :

```
class RedirectionListener
{
  /**
   * RedirectionListener constructor.
   * @param ContainerInterface $container
   * @throws \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException
   * @throws \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
   */
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
   {
      $this->router = $container->get('router');
      $this->securityTokenStorage = $container->get('security.token_storage');
  }

  /**
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
   */
   public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){

     $route = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');

     if($route !== 'fos_user_security_login' &&
        $route !== 'fos_user_resetting_reset' &&
        $route !== 'fos_user_resetting_request' &&
        $route !== 'fos_user_resetting_send_email' &&
        $route !== 'fos_user_resetting_check_email' &&
        $route !== 'fos_user_change_password' &&
        !is_object($this->securityTokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())) //this is line 46
      {
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login')));
      }
  }
}
```

This is my service :

```
services:
redirectonListener:
    class: Projects\ProjectsBundle\Listener\RedirectionListener
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And here's my firewall settings from the FOSUserBundle Docs:

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

I'm using Symfony 2.8 version. Can anyone help !

Comment: In constructor: var_dump($container->get('security.token_storage')); what says?

Comment: I could be wrong here but can't you check it like this ? if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') === false)

Comment: @Deep here's the var_dump's result : `object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage)#264 (1) { ["token":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage":private]=> NULL }`

Comment: @ElSam next for try ->getToken() and next and next.. But I think Thomas can be rights.

Comment: @Thomas I got an error, It's not working `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in classes.php line 2927:
The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.`

Comment: @Deep Although I'm authenticated, the token is `NULL`

Comment: @ElSam this is for "non-object error". And now you must find why token is null.

Comment: @Deep can you propose any way to find why it's null ?

Comment: @ElSam don't known. Something of security token settings. I haven't used it before.

Comment: Might need to adjust your listener priority.  Looks like your listener is being called before the token listener.  Hence no token.

Comment: @Dennis I've kept the FOSUser access control as it was given in the documentation `access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }`

Comment: @Cerad where can I change the priority of the my listener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set the `access_control` in your `security.yml`?

For example:

```
security:
    #[...]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # and so on, until:
        - { path: ^/restricted, role: ROLE_USER }
        # or:
        - { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

---

**Edit:** Don't forget to clear cache after changes made.

Comment: Thanks so much, I modified my security.yml file as follows :`access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }`  and it worked without even needing a redirection listener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just giving you an example so that you can modify it to meet your needs. Apart from listener way of doing it, you should look into security.yml approach in FOS. There are many examples. For example, search for `access_control` in http://www.inanzzz.com/ which will give you 6 examples to study a bit.

Note: Never inject whole container as service parameter!

A few examples.

- [Overriding controller response message with an even listener in
  symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ju0q/overriding-controller-response-message-with-an-even-listener-in-symfony)
- [Testing onKernelController event listener for user requests with
  phpspec in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/hcys/testing-onkernelcontroller-event-listener-for-user-requests-with-phpspec-in-symfony)

**SERVICE**

```
services:
    application_frontend.event_listener.order_create:
        class: Application\FrontendBundle\EventListener\OrderCreateListener
        arguments:
            - @router
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

**LISTENER**

```
namespace Application\FrontendBundle\EventListener;

use Application\FrontendBundle\Controller\OrderController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class OrderCreateListener
{
    private $router;
    private $redirectRoute = 'fos_user_security_login';
    private $invalidRoutes = ['fos_user_security_login', '...', '...'];

    public function __construct(
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();
        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if (
            $event->isMasterRequest() && // If it is user request
            $controller[0] instanceof OrderController && // Change it to your controller
            $this->isValidRoute($event) !== false
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $url = $this->router->generate($this->redirectRoute);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    private function isCreateCarMethod(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $currentRoute = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');
        if (in_array(currentRoute, $this->invalidRoutes)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I find modifying the `access_control` in the  `security.yml` file more suitable.

Comment: Good that you solved it. As I also suggested `access_control` way is the way to do it.